# Conversion from ASCII bit model to magnitude-only bit model

Tags: c, ascii

Essentially I am trying to write code that performs the conversion from ASCII bit model for the variable n to the magnitude-only bit model for the variable x.  I'm just assuming that the user enters only three digits for the input.  Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  char n[10];
  int x;
  printf("Enter three digit, nonnegative: ");
  scanf("%s" ,n);
  .
  .
  .
  printf("The number is %d\n", x);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Magnitude-only bit model: the simplest bit model is for nonnegative whole numbers. In this case each bit represents a nonnegative integer power of 2. A bit value of 0 indicates a place value of 0; a bit value of 1 indicates a place value .  The total value of the number represented is found by adding up the places values of all the bits. Example: the value represented in the 8 bits is 19: 0+0+0+16+0+0+2+1=19.

Comment: What are the "ASCII bit model" and the "magnitude-only bit model"?  Do you mean "how do I convert from a string to an integer?"

Comment: I think you may be looking for `scanf("%u", &x);` (where x is an unsigned int)

Comment: Try not to make up words. If you can explain something in simple terms, do so, and if you have to use a term that isn't commonly used, explain it.

Comment: ...or `strtol()` (`atoi()` doesn't give any error handling)

Comment: @KerrekSB - I have made an edit, explaining the terms; I hope..

Comment: @Extinct23: I still find this question highly dubious. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't all you're asking "how to parse a string as a number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While BLUEPIXY has an answer which technically does exactly what you ask for, its very complex and probably isn't what you'd want for any real program, unless you're entering an obfuscated C competition.  You probably want something more like:

```
int main() {
    int x;

    printf("Enter three digit, nonnegative: ");
    while (scanf("%d", &x) != 1 || x < 100 || x > 999) {
        printf("Not a valid input, try again: ");
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    printf("The number is %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Now this is different than what BLUEPIXY wrote and accepts a different input.  In particular, it allows (and ignores) whitespace, will ignore extra cruft after the number, and even allows entry of a 4+ digit number if the leading digits are 0s, so the final number ends up being in 100..999.  If you particularly want to disallow such inputs, you'll need something more like what he wrote.

Comment: This is a nitpick, but `fflush(stdin)` doesn't work on anything but Windows.  You want `int c; do c = getchar(); while (c != EOF && c != '\n');`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char n[10];
    int x=0;
redo:
    printf("Enter three digit, nonnegative: ");
    if(4!=scanf("%1[1-9]%1[0-9]%1[0-9]%1[\n]", &n[0],&n[1],&n[2],&n[3])){
        fflush(stdin);
        goto redo;
    }
    //printf("%s\n",n);
    x = 100*(n[0]-'0')+10*(n[1]-'0')+(n[2]-'0');
    printf("The number is %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure.  But there are cleaner ways.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - how would you make it cleaner than this?

Answer (score 0):

Both existing answers use `scanf`, which is always a mistake: in this case, it is a mistake because **`scanf` exhibits undefined behavior if the user types too many input digits**.  I am not making this up.

A better way to read user input in C is to use `fgets` (or `getline` if available and long lines are a concern) to read entire lines at a time, then convert numbers to binary with the `strto*` family of functions, which -- unlike `scanf` -- have well-defined behavior on input overflow.  They also make it enormously easier to detect and recover from other sorts of ill-formed input (it isn't really a problem in this case, but it would be if the input format were even a little more complicated).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buf[10], *endp;
    unsigned long n;
    int c;
    for (;;) {
        fputs("Enter three digit, nonnegative: ", stdout);
        fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
        n = strtoul(buf, &endp, 10);
        if (n <= 999 && *endp == '\n')
            break;
        puts("?Redo from start");
        do c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
    }
    printf("The number is %lu\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```